# What are eden tokens and how do I get them?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

There is an unlockable character called Eden which appears to require Eden tokens to unlock. How do I get tokens to unlock him or her, and how do they work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Eden is unlocked when the player defeats The Womb for the first time. Eden is a new character in The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth. Every time you beat Mom's Heart, you will get another Eden Token.

Basically you unlock Eden for defeating Mom's heart. Mom's heart can be found in The Womb, and Mom's heart can be defeated only once per run. Each kill of Mom's heart gives 1 Eden Token, which gives one run with Eden.

[Source](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Characters)

Comment: This is definitely helpful (and I upvoted), but I don't think it's complete enough to accept yet. Do we have to defeat Mom's first form or her heart? Which other bosses give tokens? I've killed Mom (the depths one) already and have no tokens, but it was an odd kill where she killed me, then my Gemini killed her, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @Fambida I did a little more research and I was wrong. So was the wiki. In a video, the guy unlocked Eden after defeating Mom's heart. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOFeFMNqMGY

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and accepted. Still need to know if further bosses such as beating sheol give more tokens, or only give tokens if mom's heart was skipped via teleports or shovel.

Comment: SO I found a far more reliable wiki post: http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Characters That states that you only get Eden tokens every time you kill Mom's heart. More Eden tokens can be achieved through each kill.